# Can't get FontSize for labels to work in ResourceDictionary when using OnPlatform

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

When using `<Style TargetType="Label">` I cant get FontSize to work with NamedSize.

Using Xamarin.Forms version : 3.4.0.1008975

Working :

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
</Style>
```

NOT working :

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                                Android="Small"
                                iOS="Medium"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have tried to change the TypeArguments to `<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="NamedSize" .../>` with no success.

I am using other propertysetters with `<OnPlatform .../>` and they work as they should. Its just FontSize.

Comment: I think you are trying to use `DynamicResource` which seems to have limitation. Check this solution: [https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65252/dynamicresource-limitation-for-onplatform-in-xaml-xamarin-forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65252/dynamicresource-limitation-for-onplatform-in-xaml-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App67"
             x:Class="App67.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="textColor" 
               x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="WinPhone" Value="Red" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Aqua" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="#80FF80" />
        </OnPlatform>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="fontSize" 
               x:TypeArguments="Font">
            <On Platform="WinPhone" Value="Bold,Large" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Bold,Large" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Bold,Large" />
        </OnPlatform>

    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Check out my style." TextColor="{StaticResource textColor}" Font="{StaticResource fontSize}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. That syntax doesn't seem to be working for me. Guessing they changed the OnPlatform in later Xamarin.Forms?

`Error    XLS0415    The attachable property 'iOS' was not found in type 'OnPlatform'. `

`Error    XLS0415    The attachable property 'Android' was not found in type 'OnPlatform'.`

And 

`Error    XLS0515    All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them. `

Comment: @MattiasGreger  I modified my answer, you can check it.